# ValueError - Could not broadcast input array from shape into shape w/ OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, numpy

I'm learning how to use OpenCV/Numpy to edit images, and am learning how to copy a part of an image and move it to another part.

I'm getting the following error with my code:

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (260,260,3) into shape (310,310,3)

```
def copy_part_of_image(image_source):
    x1 = 280
    y1 = 540
    x2 = 330
    y2 = 590

    global edited_image, ball
    rect_to_copy= image_source[x1:y1, x2:y2]
    image_source[x1-(x2-x1):y1, x1:y2] = rect_to_copy #273:533, 100:360
    edited_image = image_source
```

The idea is to take a rectangluar part of my image, and simply shift it left, so it "backs up" to the original part I cut.

As far as I can tell, my new shape is the same size (`[x1-(x2-x1):y1, x1:y2]`).  What does that error actually mean?

If I used the x/y that I commented out, it works (albeit a little off).

Here's a screenshot of part of the image, for example.  I'm trying to copy what's in the pink box, and move it left of that by the same width.

[image]

Comment: `y2-x2` is 260.  `y2-x1` is 310.  It can't write something that is 260 by 260 into a space that is 310 by 310.

Comment: @hpaulj - Apologies, I am overlooking something simple I think, but can't see it. ...My original coordinates are top left: `(280, 540)` and bottom right `(330,590)`.  If I just want to shift that space to the left by the width of that selection, I would just move the x-coordinates left `50`, right? (`x2-x1 = 50`), and keep same `y` coordinates, the new coordinates would be: top left `(230, 540)`, and bottom right `(280, 590)`, no?  Why is the shape changing?  I do see where the `260` and `310` the error shows are coming from, but frustratingly don't know how to adjust.

Comment: When you index a rectangle of an array, you specify the range of values on two sides.  `arr[10:50, 0:30]` means rows 10 to 50, and columns 0 to 30, a 40 by 30 block.  It doesn't mean top right corner of (10,50) and bottom left of (0,30).

Comment: @hpaulj - [Oohhhhh](https://media.tenor.com/images/7afd860c1003f10c5a64d0a77231a156/tenor.gif), that makes much more sense. I can get it working now, thanks a ton for that clarification!  (You can write an answer too, if you like)